# Updating to axiom-impl from 1.3.0 to 1.4.0

Tags: java, apache-axis, axiom

I'm updating the lib org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl from version 1.3.0 to 1.4.0.
After the update the class `org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMAttributeImpl` does not exist anymore.

From the [release notes](https://ws.apache.org/axiom/release-notes/1.4.0.html) the change is maybe indirect mentioned as internal refactoring. Inside the [GitHub project](https://github.com/apache/ws-axiom) I can not find the class anymore.

The question which arises for me, how can I modifiy this code that it works as expected?

```
   if (element != null) {
        OMAttribute attribute = new OMAttributeImpl();
        attribute.setLocalName("localName");
        attribute.setAttributeValue("1");
        element.addAttribute(attribute);
```

Thanks in advance,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the code directly refers to the implementation class of the `OMAttribute` interface. That's an internal implementation detail. Instead, either

- create the `OMAttribute` instance using the `createOMAttribute` method defined by `OMFactory`,
- or simply write `element.addAttribute("localName", "1", null)`.